# Sendmail not parsing tabs

Tags: python, string, parsing, sendmail

I'm using sendmail on one of my servers to send out error reports.  I'm building this report by appending to a string and then I use sendmail to send the email.  However, sendmail does not recognize the tabs in the string.  I'm wondering how do I fix this?

```
def sendMail(data):
     sendmail_location = "/usr/sbin/sendmail" # sendmail location
     p = os.popen("%s -t" % sendmail_location, "w")
     p.write("From: %s\n" % "test@example.com")
     p.write("To: %s\n" % "test2@example.com")
     p.write("Subject: the subject\n")
     p.write(data)
     status = p.close()
     if status != 0:
         print "Sendmail exit status", status
```

An example string would be:

```
data = "%d\t%s\t%s\n" % (count, message, message2)
```

Comment: what do you mean by "recognize"?  is it stripping them from the email?  it's confusing when the code you give doesn't actually have any tabs.  is the "example string" in the data?

Comment: Yes.  I'm sending sendMail(data) where data is an example input string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the way things look at the moment, that line is being treated as a header.  you need a blank line after the headers:

```
def sendMail(data):
     sendmail_location = "/usr/sbin/sendmail" # sendmail location
     p = os.popen("%s -t" % sendmail_location, "w")
     p.write("From: %s\n" % "test@example.com")
     p.write("To: %s\n" % "test2@example.com")
     p.write("Subject: the subject\n")
     p.write("\n")                                 # blank line
     p.write(data)
     status = p.close()
     if status != 0:
         print "Sendmail exit status", status
```